# How can I open a trailhead playground on my desktop browser in mobile view?

Tags: mobile, trailhead

I'm training using trailhead.salesforce.com and I want to check my playground in mobile view without the need of using a smartphone. There is a way to connect to playgrounds in mobile view with a desktop browser?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you can toggle between different device options from the Chrome Dev Tools (CTRL + SHIFT + I).

Comment: @JayantDas And in Firefox with CTRL + SHIFT + M. Thanks for your comment, it solved my problem (and I can now test it with multiple device).

Comment: You may like to add both the details from Chrome and Firefox as an answer and mark that accepted, so that this question could be resolved and someone who wants to achieve something similar will be benefited.

Answer (score 0):

#### Chrome

In Chrome, is possible to simulate a mobile viewport clicking the *Toggle Device Toolbar* or using `CTRL + SHIFT + I`. By default only the viewport is changed. Use the *Device Type* list to simulate a mobile device or desktop device.

See [Chrome devtools docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/#viewport) for more details.

#### Firefox

There are three ways to toggle *Responsive Design Mode*:

- Select *Responsive Design Mode* from the *Web Developer* sub-menu.
- Press the *Responsive Design Mode* button in the *Developer Tools* toolbox.
- Press `CTRL + SHIFT + M`.

Only the viewport size is changed by default but it's possible to choose which device should be simulated.

See [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode) for details.